# Why does the datepicker class show an empty object?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am new to the bootstrap datepicker.When I initialize it the datepicker shows. However when I try calling the datepicker it just shows an empty object?

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. If anyone can please help me I would really appreciate it.

Below is the coe I am using

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="../assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">

</head>
<body>

<div data-provide="datepicker-inline"></div>


<script>


 var datepicker =   $(".datepicker");


 //Shows empty object?
 console.log(datepicker);

</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to initialize the `datepicker` on the correct element. Since there's no element with the class `datepicker`, you're not going to get anything back in the console. You would need something like this:

```
<div class="datepicker"></div>
<script>
  var datepicker = $('.datepicker').datepicker();
  console.log(datepicker);
</script>
```

Please refer to this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3qkdkvqm/) for an example.

Comment: Kyle thanks for the response. I have tried that before. But when I try using one of their methods it doesn't work. It just appends an additional datepicker for example

When I use
datepicker = $('.datepicker').datepicker("hide");

It just appends a datepicker. 

datepicker = $('.datepicker').datepicker("hide");

Comment: This is only happening on the inline datepicker correct?